# Returning a value from a column associated with the maximum value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Sorry for the confusing title, but I didn't know how else to phrase my problem.

I have a query that returns a table of test scores, as well as some descriptions of the test itself:

`+----------------+------------+-----------+
|     student_id | test_score | test_term |
+----------------+------------+-----------+
| 1   123        |        614 | Spring    |
| 2   123        |        547 | Summer    |
| 3   123        |        628 | Fall      |
+----------------+------------+-----------+`

As you can see, Student 123 took the Math test 3 times. I'm trying to write a query that will return both the highest score that Student 123 achieved, as well as the Test Term associated with that score. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
   MAX (test_score) as "highest_math_score",
   CASE WHEN test_score = MAX(test_score) THEN test_term 
        ELSE null 
   END as "highest_test_term"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
   student_id
```

However, I am getting the error: `not a GROUP BY expression.`

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple scores tied as high scores? Choose them all, or choose a single one at random?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MAX..KEEP`:

```
SELECT student_id, 
       max(test_score), 
       max(test_term) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY test_score desc )
FROM test_data
GROUP BY student_id;
```

Full example:

```
WITH test_data ( student_id, test_score, test_term ) AS
( SELECT 123, 614, 'Spring' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 123, 547, 'Summer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 123, 628, 'Fall' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 456, 999, 'Spring' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 456, 1111, 'Summer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 456, 888, 'Fall' FROM DUAL )
SELECT student_id, max(test_score), max(test_term) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY test_score desc )
FROM test_data
GROUP BY student_id;
```

> ```
> +------------+-----------------+--------+
> | STUDENT_ID | MAX(TEST_SCORE) |  TERM  |
> +------------+-----------------+--------+
> |        123 |             628 | Fall   |
> |        456 |            1111 | Summer |
> +------------+-----------------+--------+
> ```

Comment: Wow. First time I see `KEEP`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want :

```
SELECT MAX(test_score) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id) AS "highest_math_score",
       (CASE WHEN test_score = MAX(test_score) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id) 
             THEN test_term 
        END) AS "highest_test_term"
FROM Table1;
```

However, you can also use `dense_rank()` :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY test_score DESC) AS seq
      FROM Table1 t
     ) t1
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Another option would be subquery with correlation approach :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE test_score = (SELECT MAX(t1.test_score) FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.student_id = t.student_id);
```

Comment: Like this answer. It gracefully deals with multiple max values.

Comment: I think you may be missing something.  That will return multiple rows for each student.  I expect the OP just wants _one_ row per student.

Comment: Maybe he wants multiple ones. I don't know. Let's ask him.

Answer (score 1):

Without any window functions:

```
select t1.student_id, t."highest_math_score"
  from t1 
  join  
(SELECT
   MAX (test_score) as "highest_math_score", student_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY
   student_id)t on t.student_id = t1.student_id and t.highest_math_score = t1.test_score
```